# How to check if equals or is within X days in MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, where-clause, unix-timestamp

I have a column called `submit_timestamp` which holds a `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`), what I want to do now is do a `SELECT` query and within the `WHERE` clause ensure the `submit_timestamp` equals or is within X number of days.

(Demonstration purposes only):

```
SELECT id
FROM   submissions
WHERE  submit_timestamp = 'EQUALS OR IS WITHIN X NUMBER OF DAYS FROM submit_timestamp'
       AND id = 2
```

All help appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compute the two times you want to compare to in your application before you construct the query. All programming languages will have a function to give you the current timestamp (i.e. `time()` in PHP). To get "X days from now", add 60*60*24*X seconds to the timestamp.

```
SELECT id
FROM   submissions
WHERE  submit_timestamp >= $THE_CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
       AND submit_timestamp <= ($THE_CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + 60*60*24*X)
       AND id = 2
```

Now you're just comparing integers. Unlike Johan's solution, MySQL will be able to use an index on the column for the comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id 
FROM submissions 
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(submit_timestamp) 
  BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 2 DAY)
  AND id = 2;
```

`A BETWEEN B AND C` does `A >= B AND A <= C`.
It just communicates the intent better :-)

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime

**EDIT**
Or even better:

```
SELECT id 
FROM submissions 
WHERE submit_timestamp BETWEEN UNIXTIMESTAMP() 
  AND unixtimestamp(DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 2 DAY))
  AND id = 2;
```

As Dan correctly explains, this allows MySQL to use an index on `submit_timestamp`, which the above code does not.

Note that `UNIXTIMESTAMP()` with no arguments returns `UNIXTIMESTAMP(NOW())`
See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp

Comment: Too my knowledge NOW() returns the current time in the default MySQL format, so just curious whether you've considered that submit_timestamp is a unix timestamp (without any format)?

Comment: @newbtophp: presumably not, but +1 to his answer nonetheless. adjusting the query to your needs after reading mysql's datetime functions is certainly in your skillset.